# How can i create multiple dictionaries for initial letters from a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, random

I want to create lists from a list. In the main list i have 1300+ dictionary words (most common) for English to Spanish. for example:

```
words = {"hablar":"to speak","reir":"to laugh","comer":"to eat"}
```

and 1300+ words like this. I do not want to seperate them manually for initials. I want to make a program to seperate them automatically like this;

```
    a_words = {words with a}
    b_words = {words with b}
    c_words = {"comer":"to eat"}
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    h_words = {"hablar":"to speak"}
```

my program will automatically create dictionaries per initial letters. And i will make a random selection function so when i run the program, it will show me a word in Spanish and i will type it in English so i will be practicing. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Where are you stuck at? Do you know how to: (1) loop over a dict (2) add an element to a dict? (do note that make 26 variables is a bad idea, use a dict instead)

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work ?

Comment: It's unclear if you have a dictionary or a list that contains all your words. In the example you show us a dictionary but you refer to it as "main list". Please make this clear.

Comment: i have a word txt file 1300+ more words in it. I will put them in a dictionary or list or tuple i dont even know which one of these is the right technique for create a program. I don't want to put them custom lists/dics manually. I want to put all of them in same list/dic and with a code they will be in custom lists/dics for initials. How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you can use compressions such as:

```
a_words = {k:v for k,v in allwords.items() if k.lower().startswith('a')}
```

But of course you would be better off having a dictionary of dictionaries with:

```
split_dicts = {L:{k:v for k,v in allwords.items() if k.lower().startswith(L)} for L in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"}  
# May need to change the list of characters depending on language.
```

Note in earlier pythons you may need to use `iter_items()` rather than `items()` in the above.

Expanding the second compression for clarity:

```
split_dicts = dict()  # This will become a dictionary of dictionaries
for L in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":  # Iterate the letters
    # May need to change the list of characters depending on language
    split_dict[L] = dict()  # Add a dictionary for this letter
    for k,v in allwords.items():  # Python 2 use .iter_items()
        if k.lower().startswith(L):  # If lowercase of the word starts with this letter
             split_dict[L][k] = v  # Add to the dictionary for this letter an entry for k
```

You can then use random:

```
import random
letter = random.choice('abcdefghijlkmnopqrstuvwxyz')
s_word = random.choice(list(split_dict[letter].keys()))
e_word = split_dict[letter][s_word]
```

Comment: Thanks for your advices. I think i will make it with first way because i did not understand the second one. But i want to ask another question, can i select randomly words if i use the first code? I mean i will code a random selection function for each letter. So i can select letters which one i want to practice.

Comment: @ArdaAltun I have expanded my answer to make the second option clearer and to show how you could use it.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help!!

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach. Using `collections.defaultdict`

**Demo:**

```
import collections
words = {"hablar":"to speak","reir":"to laugh","comer":"to eat"}
d = collections.defaultdict(list)
for k,v in words.items():
    d[k[0].lower()].append({k: v})
print(d)

print("Words in H")
print(d["h"])
```

**Output:**

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'h': [{'hablar': 'to speak'}], 'c': [{'comer': 'to eat'}], 'r': [{'reir': 'to laugh'}]})

Words in H
[{'hablar': 'to speak'}]
```